# QSlider in PySide6 Won't Emit a Signal

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

So I've been trying to develop a video player with Qt's PySide 6 using VLC as a backend to render the video just for the fun of it. I've gotten the player and a QSlider to appear as a widget in the main window, but no matter what I try with the slider it just doesn't seem to want to connect a signal to a function within the same class. I've even had the function empty except for a print function, so nothing should really be impeding the script from running unless I'm missing something. So I'm not really sure what I'm getting wrong here.

```
import sys, vlc
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QSlider, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class Player(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.media = self.instance.media_new("Untitled Project.webm")
        self.create_ui()
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        self.player.play()
        self.player.set_position(0.2)

    def create_ui(self):
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.videoframe = QFrame()
        if sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
            self.player.set_xwindow(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "win32":
            self.player.set_hwnd(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":
            self.player.set_nsobject(self.videoframe.winId())
        self.palette = self.videoframe.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(0,0,0))

        self.positionslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionslider.setToolTip("Position")
        self.positionslider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.positionslider.sliderPressed.connect(self.slider_position)
        self.vboxlay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxlay.addWidget(self.videoframe)
        self.vboxlay.addWidget(self.positionslider)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.vboxlay)
        self.positionslider.sliderMoved.connect(self.slider_position)
    def slider_position(self):
        print("Slider moved")
        pos = self.positionslider.value()
        self.player.set_position(pos / 1000)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        video = Player()
        self.setCentralWidget(video.widget)
        self.resize(QSize(640, 430))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Typo: change to `self.video = Player()`, as the `Player` instance gets garbage collected. Besides, subclassing QWidget for that is pointless for the way you're using it: just use *it* instead of creating a *new* widget. The `Widget` class is also useless.

Comment: It's not useless, because I'm going to embed it into another screen, so it'll be a widget in it. I just haven't gotten around to it yet because I'm still learning. You are right about the Widget class though because that's left over from me playing around. Purely an accident.

Comment: As said, *that* QWidget subclass (`Player`) is pointless *for the way you're using it*. And if you're using it in another "screen" (meaning that the `Player` instance is in a widget, while the `video.widget` is in another), then it's conceptually wrong to have an attribute that is actually part of a different object, especially considering that you're creating `self.widget` as a *Qt child* of `Player`, and *then* you're actually reparenting it by setting it as central widget.

Comment: The `self.widget` was just something I saw somewhere else. I didn't actually know whether or not is was needed. So thank you for that information.

Comment: Me removing the `self.widget` actually ended up being the solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue, pointed out to me by musicamante, was that I actually had the widget I was going to embed, also be a widget within itself. This led to an odd miscommunication within PySide (or so I believe) that led to having the signals not connect. Thank you again, musicamante, and I'll post the updated code below so that others can see the fix to my mistake.

```
import sys, vlc
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QFrame, QSlider, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class Player(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.media = self.instance.media_new("Untitled Project.webm")
        self.create_ui()
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        self.player.play()
        self.player.set_position(0.2)

    def create_ui(self):
        self.videoframe = QFrame()
        if sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
            self.player.set_xwindow(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "win32":
            self.player.set_hwnd(self.videoframe.winId())
        elif sys.platform == "darwin":
            self.player.set_nsobject(self.videoframe.winId())
        self.palette = self.videoframe.palette()
        self.palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(0,0,0))

        self.positionslider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionslider.setToolTip("Position")
        self.positionslider.setMaximum(1000)
        self.positionslider.sliderPressed.connect(self.slider_position)
        self.vboxlay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxlay.addWidget(self.videoframe)
        self.vboxlay.addWidget(self.positionslider)
        self.setLayout(self.vboxlay)
        self.positionslider.sliderMoved.connect(self.slider_position)
    def slider_position(self):
        print("Slider moved")
        pos = self.positionslider.value()
        self.player.set_position(pos / 1000)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")
        self.video = Player()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.video)
        self.resize(QSize(640, 430))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: There's no "odd miscommunication", I've already explained: the class instance (`video`) had no reference (it was a local variable), so it was garbage collected as soon as the `__init__` returns, and its `slider_position` function along with it. If the concept is not clear, I suggest you to do some research about variable scope/lifespan and garbage collection.

Comment: Actually you hadn't really explained that, but I appreciate the clarification. I am familiar with how garbage collection works on Java, but I'm not too familiar with it on Python. I'd even read somewhere that Python didn't even have a GC, but I assume that's wrong now which actually makes more sense that it would be. Again, I appreciate your efforts to help me out with this, as I'm still pretty new to Python.

Comment: I did wrote that in my very first comment: "the Player instance gets garbage collected." I don't know where you read that Python doesn't have garbage collection, but they are **extremely** wrong. Since you're new to Python, I'd suggest you to do some research on both GC *and* variable scopes.